# How to Read XML to Class Object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
<Session>
<bIsImages>False</bIsImages>
<bIsPlayMedia>False</bIsPlayMedia>
<bIsSubject>False</bIsSubject>
<bIsVideo>False</bIsVideo>
<dtCreDate>2012-07-23</dtCreDate>
<dtSes_Date1>2001-01-01</dtSes_Date1>
<dtSes_Date2>2001-01-01</dtSes_Date2>
<dtSes_Date3>2001-01-01</dtSes_Date3>
<nClient_ID>32</nClient_ID>
<nDelay>32</nDelay>
<nImage_ID>32</nImage_ID>
<nOperator_ID>32</nOperator_ID>
<nSession_ID>32</nSession_ID>
<nVitality>32</nVitality>
<strDescr>qi stagnatie abq</strDescr>
<strMediaPath></strMediaPath>
<strName>qi stagnatie abq</strName>
<strPrimCause></strPrimCause>
<strSubjectPath>IDF_Eric duBosc.JPG</strSubjectPath>
</Session>
<SessionProgramData>
</SessionProgramData><SessionSubProgramData>
</SessionSubProgramData><SessionTuningData>

  <SessionTuning>
    <SessionTuning_ID>717</SessionTuning_ID>
    <Session_ID>70</Session_ID>
    <Tuning>8285-100</Tuning>
    <TuningDescr>Disturbance by Qistagnatie in general</TuningDescr>
    <TuningIsNegative>true</TuningIsNegative>
    <TuningAddInfo>70</TuningAddInfo>
    <Amp>2.2</Amp>
    <Amp2 />
    <Amp3>0.1</Amp3>
    <Amp4>5.1</Amp4>
    <Amp5>1.0</Amp5>
    <Amp6 />
    <TunFreq>8285-100</TunFreq>
    <TunFreq2 />
    <TunFreq3>8285-100</TunFreq3>
    <TunFreq4 />
    <TunFreq5 />
    <TunFreq6 />
    <Revision2>false</Revision2>
    <Revision3>false</Revision3>
    <Revision4>false</Revision4>
    <Revision5>false</Revision5>
    <Revision6>false</Revision6>
    <AlreadyBalanced>false</AlreadyBalanced>
    <ImagePath />
    <Amp7 />
    <TunFreq7 />
    <Revision7>0</Revision7>
    <Description />
  </SessionTuning>

  ....So on

</SessionTuningData>
<Client>
<nClient_ID>32</nClient_ID>
<strAddress></strAddress>
<strCity></strCity>
<strCountry></strCountry>
<strFirstName>Eric</strFirstName>
<strImage>IDF_Eric duBosc.JPG</strImage>
<strLastName>Bosc</strLastName>
<strMI>du</strMI>
<strNote>ikke</strNote>
<strPhoneNum></strPhoneNum>
<strPostalCode></strPostalCode>
<strState></strState>
<strWorkPhone></strWorkPhone>
</Client>
<SE-5 />
</DocumentElement>
```

And the class as below:

```
    public class clsSessionTuningData
    {
        public int nSessionTuning_ID;
        public int nSession_ID;
        public int nTuning_ID;
        public string strTuning;
        public string strTuningDescr;
        public string Description;
        public bool bTuningIsNegative;
        public int nTuningAddInfo;
        public string strAmp;
        public string strAmp2;
        public string strAmp3;
        public string strAmp4;
        public string strAmp5;
        public string strAmp6;
        public string strAmp7;

        public DateTime strRevDate;
        public DateTime strRevDate2;
        public DateTime strRevDate3;
        public DateTime strRevDate4;
        public DateTime strRevDate5;
        public DateTime strRevDate6;
        public DateTime strRevDate7;

        public string strTunFreq;
        public string strTunFreq2;
        public string strTunFreq3;
        public string strTunFreq4;
        public string strTunFreq5;
        public string strTunFreq6;
        public string strTunFreq7;
        public bool bRevision2;
        public bool bRevision3;
        public bool bRevision4;
        public bool bRevision5;
        public bool bRevision6;
        public bool bRevision7;
        public bool bAlreadyBalanced;
        public string strImagePath;
    }
```

So How can I get values for each tag of `<SessionTuningData>` in array of `clsSessionTuningData` object .?

Comment: Have you by any chance tried googling serialisation of xml to class? Or even searched this site? there are plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your class as serializable.

I would have expected some `[XmlElement]` attributes at least to appear in the code of anyone who had read any tutorial.

[Like this one](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)

```
public class Movie
{
  [XmlElement("MovieName")]
  public string Title
  { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("MovieRating")]
  public float Rating
  { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("MovieReleaseDate")]
  public DateTime ReleaseDate
  { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like xsd.exe to create a xsd file and from here you can serialise using

http://snipplr.com/view/2660/

it might not create the exact same xml but it will be close...

As an aside its probably easier to serialise to json instead of xml using newtonsoft json

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Decorate your class properties with xml attributes (e.g: XmlElement, XmlAttribute) (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes)
2. Implement IXmlSerializable (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)
3. Or using DataContractSerializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)