# Is it possible to get populate class object from xml?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file like this:

```
  <CommissionTypes>
    <Type>CPA</Type>
    <Lender>
      <Seq>001</Seq>
      <PostUrl>http://www.mysite.com</PostUrl>
    </Lender>
  </CommissionTypes>
</Lenders>
```

Having got the data like this:

```
var config = XDocument.Load(xml);
```

I need to map it to a class collection, the class is structured like this:

```
public class Lender
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Seq { get; set; }
    public string PostUrl { get; set; }

    public void Lender(string type, int seq, string postUrl)
    {
        Type = type;
        Seq = seq;
        PostUrl = postUrl;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to do this for some time using linq, but without success as yet. What i want to do is retrieve all lenders with in the type "CPA" or any other type.

Any advice?

// *** UPDATE *** //

The update below is where I'm currently at. Its not working, getting a 'object reference not set to an instance' error wgere arrow is.

```
<CommissionTypes>
  <Type type="CPA">
    <Lender>
      <Seq>001</Seq>
      <PostUrl>http://www.mysite.com</PostUrl>
    </Lender>
  </Type>
</CommissionTypes>

    public static List<Lender> GetLenders(string xml)
    {
        var myXml = XDocument.Load(xml);

        var lenders = new List<Lender>();

        lenders = (from type in myXml.Descendants("Type")
               where type.Attribute("type").Value == "CPA"
        ===>   select new Lender(
                "CPA",
                type.Element("Seq").Value.ConvertTo<int>(),
                type.Element("PostUrl").Value)).ToList();

        return lenders;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154924/how-to-read-xml-to-class-object/15155075#15155075)

Comment: Sorry, thats not what I'm looking for

Comment: @dotnetnoob Where are your attributes? Look at the example in Peretz's link, that is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrect, because `Seq` is not a direct child of `Lender` element.

```
public static List<Lender> GetLenders(string xml)
{
    var myXml = XDocument.Load(xml);

    var lenders = new List<Lender>();

    lenders = (from type in myXml.Descendants("Type")
               where type.Attribute("type").Value == "CPA"
               from lender in type.Elements("Lender")
               select new Lender(
                    "CPA",
                    (int)lender.Element("Seq"),
                    (string)lender.Element("PostUrl"))).ToList();

    return lenders;
}
```